# Wifi not getting connected

Tags: linux-mint, wifi, internet

I installed Linux mint 17 on my PC a month back. I did not have any issues of WiFi until 2-3 days back.

2-3 days back I updated few packages through the update manager and since then the WiFi is not getting connected. It shows that my router is available for connection but does not provide any option to connect to the router. And sometimes it gets switched to Airplane mode.

I have both Windows and Linux Mint on my PC. The WiFi gets connected in Windows but not in Mint.

Please help.

Comment: Can you connect with ethernet cable? Problems is a nice way to start learning linux :) It seems it is an `rfkill` related issue. Try: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=90&t=101760 http://askubuntu.com/questions/92968/enable-wireless-adaptors-on-dell-1018-inspiron http://askubuntu.com/questions/119195/cannot-disable-airplane-mode http://askubuntu.com/questions/468406/wifi-is-disabled-and-network-applets-enable-wfi-is-not-clickable If you are new to linux and you don't get it fixed in a couple of hours, save some time backing up Mint's valuable files and reinstall Mint.

Comment: @pidosaurus i checked through rfkill list ... it showed " Soft blocked: No, Hard Blocked: No " ... It shows that WiFi is enabled . It also shows the available connections, but it does not provide any option to connect it to the routers.

Comment: Ok, since it seems you need to learn the cause of the problem and not just reinstall Mint, I propose trying to connect through the console manually. If that's successful, then probably the "system" is ok, but the graphical interface (or the networking service) has some problem. You can try disabling Router's encryption as a first step. http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/354 gives a general idea and https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_network_configuration#Manual_setup is more comprehensive (it also tells how to connect with encryption)

Comment: Why not try to understand which update caused the problem? Go through the recently updated packages (there is a list somewhere, there must be) and post them, so that the problem can be localized more easily.